# Mount Keyboard permanently on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to make the keyboard always visible on the screen?

The screen has:

- one `TextInput` (multiline)
- two `FlatList`

When I type something in `TextInput` it is ok but when I change something to FlatList the keyboard is hidden

I want the keyboard to be always visible regardless of what I do on the screen

What I tested:

- `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` not working
- at the beginning I have `autoFocus` set to `TextInput` and with every change when the keyboard is hidden show it again. I thought that I could do it so that the transition was not visible but it does not work as it should be

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.nameInput.focus();
    }, 1);
  }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener to `keyboardWillHide` and focus your `nameInput` `TextField` when the event is triggered.

Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from "react-native";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardWillHide",
      this._keyboardWillHide,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardWillHide() {
    // Focus the input
  }

  render() {
    // Your UI here
  }
}
```

More information can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html

Comment: Did not work. The effect is unchanged